Why is layered navigation not updating after choosing a filter, in PWA Studio
Why aren't filters updating after choosing a filter, this issue exists for all versions.
So when I select a filter and after it I select another, I get the message "Products not found", because if the filters were updated, there would be no second filter to select.
go to the page of any category and select a filter, the products will be updated, but the filters will remain the same.
